# ios textview attributedText load html font working in device but not simulator

Tags: html, swift, uitextview

I am using Text View in Scroll View to load html content like the code below. Everything works fine when test on **device**. But when I test on **simulator**, the content disappear but you still can copy/paste them. [See the no content image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNiND.png) This case happens when the **html string too long**.

It will work when I delete the css **"font-family: (font!.fontName); font-size: (font!.pointSize)"** or disable the **"scrolling  enable"** of text view.

Any advices are welcome, thanks!

```
let screenWidth = htmlContentTv.frame.width - 10
let font = UIFont(name: "Univers-Light", size: 16)
let html = "<html><head><style>img{max-width:\(screenWidth)px;height:auto !important;width:auto !important;};</style> </head>" + "<body><div style=\"font-family: \(font!.fontName); font-size: \(font!.pointSize);color: #000000; line-height:1.5;\">%@</div></body></html>"
let processHtml = String(format: html, article.content!)

do {
    let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(
        data: processHtml.data(using:.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                   NSFontAttributeName: font!],
        documentAttributes: nil)
    htmlContentTv.attributedText = attrStr
} catch let error {
    print("html error \(error)" )
}
```

Comment: `options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSFontAttributeName: font!],` The `NSFontAttributeName` part should be useless. It's not read (check the doc). Instead use `NSMutableAttributedString` instead of `NSAttributedString` and do `attrStr.addAttributes(_ attrs: NSFontAttributeName:font!], range:NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length)` or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good way to show html text, if you do not have clear reason to use UITextView, you can you use for this case UIWebView:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlText, baseURL: nil)
```

And if you need change color or font you can use this extension

```
extension String
{
    func htmlFormattedString(font:UIFont, color: UIColor) -> String
    {
        let numberOfColorComponents:Int = color.cgColor.numberOfComponents
        let colorComponents = color.cgColor.components

        var colorHexString = ""
        if numberOfColorComponents == 4 {
            let red = (colorComponents?[0])! * 255
            let green = (colorComponents?[1])! * 255
            let blue = (colorComponents?[2])! * 255

            colorHexString = NSString(format:"%02X%02X%02X", Int(red), Int(green), Int(blue)) as String
        } else if numberOfColorComponents == 2 {
            let white = (colorComponents?[0])! * 255

            colorHexString = NSString(format:"%02X%02X%02X", Int(white), Int(white), Int(white)) as String
        } else {
            return "Color format noch supported"
        }

        return NSString(format: "<html>\n <head>\n <style type=\"text/css\">\n body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@; color:#%@;}\n </style>\n </head>\n <body>%@</body>\n </html>", font.familyName, String(stringInterpolationSegment: font.pointSize), colorHexString, self) as String
    }
}
```

To use it you just call `htmlText.htmlFormattedString(font:someFont,color:.red)` before you load text to WebView

Comment: Thanks, I used the web view at first. The reason why I don't use UIWebView is I want to put this html stuff in scroll view with some other components. If I use UIWebView inside that, I have to disable the scroll in web view and calculate the height of web view manually.

Comment: You can use UIScrollView, there put UIWebView with height as him content size. If you need code example notify me :)

Comment: Is that still working if I'd like to put other components in scroll view?

Comment: Yes, sure. You just need set constraints to UIScrollView and other Views.